# Handlebars helper for running totals?

Tags: javascript, json, reporting, handlebars.js

I have an html 5 Angular application that needs business reporting customizable by the end user.  A back end Node REST api supplies the JSON data for the reports.

My solution I'm considering is to use Handlebars as the report template "engine".  The data would come from the server with an accompanying template that would get compiled at the client side at run time and displayed on a page.

Users would be able to customize the template and save it back.

The sticking point is running totals.  I want to do this in the template and I've tried making custom helpers but I am having trouble reliably keeping the state.

Here is what I tried:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('runningTotal', function(k, v, r) {
//k=Key, v=numeric value, r='root' key in the json data
if (!r[k]) {
    r[k] = v;
} else {
    r[k] += v;
}
return r[k]; });
```

And in my template I call it like this:

```
 '{{runningTotal "labor" lineTotal ../../../rptState}}' +                              
 '{{/each}}' +
```

The parameters being passed to the "runningTotal" helper are "labor" which is the name of the key to store the running total under, "lineTotal" which is the name of the existing JSON data key that needs to be kept totalled, and finally "rptState" which is the existing JSON data key that will hold the running total.

The JSON data object has an automatic empty object key added at the very top level called rptState to hold this kind of data.

What I'm seeing is that it works perfectly until the end of the /each block at which point it seems that the JSON data "resets" back to it's original state and my helper's added keys are lost.  This means I can't do grand totals or even properly print the running totals as at the bottom of an each block since it's reset at the end of the each blocks.

Am I going about this correctly and just missing some detail or is there a better way entirely?

Comment: I'm confused on why you would need handlebars on top of angular. Use angular form bindings, let the user change them, then do an api call with the object back.

Comment: My thinking was to make a solution that is not dependant on Angular, however now that you mention it maybe that's not an issue (though I'm not sure if it in any way resolves my problem as it's essentially the same thing perhaps). I'll look into it, thank you Christopher.

Comment: I think you won't have an issue with implementation and data modeling your object if you're already familiar with angular. :}